# Site Template Images - Borders, Lines, Curves

Tags: images, graphics

Most of the sites posted here and elsewhere mentioning sites with free full-sized backgrounds.  I was curious if there is a site that has free graphics for creating a template, with images like corner radiuses, gradient borders, and other smaller graphics to help put together the site template.  That's something I'm in need of, and was wondering if its around anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link http://designmoo.com/category/ui-elements/. You can find a collection of buttons, navigation menus, forms and other user interface elements. Hope, it will meet your requirements.

Comment: do you know any resource like designmoo but for html snippets?

Comment: http://snipplr.com/popular/language/html hope this helps.